# In NodeJS, 'Decimal' works also as 'decimal'

Tags: javascript, node.js, decimal, decimal.js

I am installing and using package `decimal.js` in NodeJS.

This package is described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal.js).

All the examples state that I should be using `Decimal`. For some reason, it also works when using `decimal`.

What is the rationale behind this?

I've found a similar question on C# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915938/difference-between-decimal-and-decimal), which states exactly what I sort of speculated:

The symbol `decimal` is declared as an alias for `Decimal`.

Is it the same in NodeJS, and how exactly do you go about aliasing something in JavaScript?

For the record, I am importing the package as follows:

```
import Decimal from 'decimal.js';
```

And as already implied, this seems to work just as well:

```
import decimal from 'decimal.js';
```

Comment: Probably because that's the default export from the module; so, you can name it anything you want when you import it.

Comment: @canon: So it's me who determines the name then? I don't quite understand, isn't there a class with some explicit name inside this package that I need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different types of export. Named exports and Default exports.You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

From that Page:
Named exports are useful to export several values. During the import, it is mandatory to use the same name of the corresponding object.
But a default export can be imported with any name.

Comment: OK, so this is in fact a completely different reason than that stated in the C# answer... right?

Comment: Yes. It has nothing to do with C# answer.